# Cornice ACL not working

Tags: python, permissions, acl, pyramid, cornice

I was have been trying to implement acl for services in cornice without any luck. I've tried using the example given in the tests from this url:

https://github.com/mozilla-services/cornice/blob/d390eef6681d8541b3d8ee3cdd7229b0cc3e7615/cornice/tests/test_pyramidhook.py

I basically just did copy paste of the following code and changed the acl to always deny permission:

```
def my_acl(request):
    return [DENY_ALL]

service = Service(name="service", path="/service", acl=my_acl)


@service.get()
def return_404(request):
    raise HTTPNotFound()


@service.put(permission='update')
def update_view(request):
    return "updated_view"
```

I was hoping that with DENY_ALL the service would never return the "updated_view" response, however that was all I got when doing the put request. Is there any setup or anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you use ACLAuthorizationPolicy when configuring you app?

Comment: Yes, I also noted that even though the authentication policy was being called the AuthenticationPolicy callback was not when using cornice.

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you initialize you authentication and authorization?

Comment: [Authentication and Authorization Setup](http://pastebin.com/3frVFUSR)

Comment: You might want to have a look at how we have implemented it in Kinto: https://github.com/mozilla-services/cliquet/tree/master/cliquet